# Ajax post with multiple parameters in Razor

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, post, razor

In ASP.NET Core + Razor I want to do an ajax post with multiple parameters. The amount of parameter could vary. I have products with Ids and an amount for every ProductId. I want to send this data to the server. The ProductAndAmount tuple is created and stringyfied. The data in the ajax post is available. But the parameter1 in my OnPostReduceProducts() method is null. I also used the AntiForgeryToken.
Why is the parameter1 still null?

BuyProducts.js file

```
function buyProducts(nItems) {

    document.getElementById("buyButton").innerHTML = "bought products";

    var totalPriceOfAllProductsLabel = document.getElementById('totalPriceLabel');
    totalPriceOfAllProductsLabel.textContent = "0.00";

    // reduce items from stock    
    var objectArray = new Array();
    var tuple = Object.freeze({ Id: "1", Amount: "2" });
    objectArray.push(tuple);
    var dataToPost = JSON.stringify({ parameter1: objectArray });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        url: "/StockItems/Edit?handler=ReduceProducts",
        data: dataToPost,
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
        }
    });
}
```

Data field in the ajax post

```
{"parameter1":[{"Id":"1","Amount":"2"}]}
```

Part of my Edit.cshtml

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/js/BuyProducts.js"></script>
}
```

Parts of my Edit.cshtml.cs

```
public void OnPostReduceProducts(List<ProductAndAmount> parameter1)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("OnPostReduceProducts() is running");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(parameter1[0].Id);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(parameter1[0].Amount);
}

public class ProductAndAmount
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Did I provide all necessary parts of code to answer this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
var dataToPost = JSON.stringify({ parameter1: objectArray });
```

to

```
var dataToPost = JSON.stringify(objectArray);
```

Change ajax(add contenttype):

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        url: "/StockItems/Edit?handler=ReduceProducts",
        data: dataToPost,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        headers: {
            RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
        }
    });
```

Change action:

```
public void OnPostReduceProducts([FromBody]List<ProductAndAmount> parameter1)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("OnPostReduceProducts() is running");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(parameter1[0].Id);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(parameter1[0].Amount);
}
```

**Update:**

If it is still not working, you can delete cache and retry.

Comment: I tried this, but parameter1 in the C# method is still null yet.

Comment: I have upadated my answer,you also need to change your ajax and action.

Comment: I don't know why. In the browser it is telling me, that parameter1 is null. But I deleted parameter1 in ajax. Is this a browser cache problem?

Comment: {"parameter1":[{"Id":"1","Amount":"2"}]} in the data field! But where is this parameter1 comes from? I only use it in the C# method.

Comment: Because model binding a model to action,don't need to tell the model name,it will automatically bind the passed data to your parameter1 in OnPostReduceProducts.Can you work with the answer?

Comment: I renamed parameter1 to parameter2 but in the browser parameter1 is still displayed. :/

Comment: After deleting my cache your version was working. Could you mention this in your answer please, then I can accept. Thank you.

Comment: The most important statement that worked for me was "[FromBody]" in the ASP.NET Core controller - Thanks a lot